# Track down a caller from his ID

Tags: internet, phone, voip, tracking

I use my company soft-fone for work. I never shared the tel # with anyone outside the company. Yet I keep getting a call from a caller ID which is obviously an a VOIP caller ID ( not a number just 5 digits like 45664 ) and the same person keeps making lewd and offensive remarks  and this guy is an abs psycho. I am not sure if he is stalking me  outside too. I cant block him but fact that he knowns a confidential work # tells me , he works within the company. I know , now one in my vicinity where I sit , who can do it. Most of them are women and the voice is different.  I scared. I want to find out who he is. How can I get his IP from my soft-fone server ( cisco soft-fone )

Comment: ***You*** don't. The police do

Comment: Sounds like a question pertinent to your local IT, *no*?

Comment: Or that should be asked on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ? At the very least, the company can change your internal number, but it is their problem, not yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See either in softphone logs (but I don't know if cisco is making them) or using Wireshark where does the call is coming from. It might be direct IP call or call from PABX. If it comes from PABX then refer to PABX logs.